# Missing IInMemoryBusFactoryConfigurator.SetHost() (or equivalent) in MassTransit v5

Tags: masstransit

After using both the Azure Service Bus and RabbitMQ transports successfully, we're now looking into using the InMemory transport for testing purposes. Our current solution would require us to have multiple bus instances interfacing with each other in a single (Unit Test) process. The [documentation](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/transports.html#sharing-transports) on this topic indicates that this should be possible using the`IInMemoryBusFactoryConfigurator.SetTransportProvider()` method. However, this method doesn't seem to be available in MassTransit v5. I've read somewhere that this method has been replaced with the `IInMemoryBusFactoryConfigurator.SetHost()` method, but again this method is not available in MassTransit v5 (removed in [this](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/commit/677d6df62c726d37c68871c66a7904787ab66ff5) commit).

Is there currently any way to share the transport cache between multiple bus instances?

Comment: There is not, that ability was removed well over a year ago, perhaps two years ago. If you need to test with a real broker in between two bus instances, consider standing up RabbitMQ in a docker container as part of your test runner and using it. Or you can just put all of your receive endpoints on a single bus.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clearing that up. I'll look into your suggestions.